# "transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(), tolower)" can't be compiled in Xcode 5

Tags: c++, xcode, stl

I'm new in using stl c++. and I copied this function from the book:

```
string ConverToLowerCase(string s)  
{  
    transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(), tolower);//Compile Error:No matching function for call to 'transform'
    return s;  
}
```

And I have #include cctype and algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR:
The problem is that `tolower` is an `int(int)` function, so the `UnaryOperation` type deduction is not obvious in your call to `transform`.

Details:
`transform` 's last argument should be a unary_operation, with the following properties (from [CPPReference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform)):

> unary operation function object that will be applied.
>   The signature of the function should be equivalent to the following:
>   Ret fun(const Type &a);
>   The signature does not need to have const &. 
>   The type Type must be such that an object of type InputIt can be dereferenced and then implicitly converted to Type. The type Ret must be such that an object of type OutputIt can be dereferenced and assigned a value of type Ret.

`tolower`'s signature is:

```
int tolower( int ch );
```

So it does not really fill these requirements. Some compilers might be smarter about type deduction and let this pass, but in your case, you need to make it look like a `char fun(const char&)` function (or `char fun(char)`, because references to characters don't really make sense).
This can be done using e.g. a lambda function:

```
string ConverToLowerCase(string s) {  
    std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(), [](char c) { 
      return std::tolower(c); 
    });
    return s;  
}
```

Or, if lambdas scare you, you can do this with a plain old function adapter:

```
char tolower_char(char c) {
    return std::tolower(c);
}

string ConverToLowerCase(string s) {  
    std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(), &tolower_char);
    return s;  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. But I already type "using namespace std;". I'm sorry for omitting that line.

Comment: I improved my answer a bit after testing it. Long story short: `tolower` can not be understood as a `char` processing function without some additional syntax

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works now! But i feel even more confused. Could you please explain this in detail to me?